# Difference between double quotes and single quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, quotation-marks

What is the difference between double quotation marks `""` and single quotation marks `''` in Ruby?

As far as I have seen this seems to only be a choice of preference and there is no change in function unless the two are accidentally mixed, ie `"Some String'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-quotes interpolates.

Single-quotes do not, e.g.,

```
puts "Hi #{42+5}"
=> "Hi 47"

puts 'Hi #{42+5}'
=> "Hi #{42+5}"
```